# Android: 'slideEdge' no longer works

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat, slide

I am using the tag like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<transitionSet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">

    <slide
        app:slideEdge="top"/>

    <changeBounds />
</transitionSet>
```

When I build my project I get the following  error:

```
Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'slideEdge' in package 'com.mypackage'
```

This code worked yesterday, but doesn't work today.

Here are my dependencies. The target version is SDK level 23 and min version is SDK level 19:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one whole year later and I have found a solution:

Rebuild and clean the project.

For some reason, android studio and gradle get confused sometimes as to what is and isn't part of your project.